# Can a Solidity function accept an object from JS. For example, can addTenant(**Tenant tenantObj**) accept Tenant Object?

Tags: solidity

```
contract Tenants{

  address admin;
  uint256[] public tenatIDs;
  mapping(bytes32 => Tenant) tenantDetails;

  function Tenants() public{

      admin = msg.sender;
  }

  struct Tenant{

      string uniqueID;
      string name;
      uint256 flatNum;
      uint256 phoneNum;
      uint256 advanceAmt;
      uint256 rent;
  }


  function addTenant(**Tenant tenantObj**) public{
          //code goes here
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, functions can only accept parameters of types known to the contract. You could create a JSON string in javascript and pass that, then somehow deconstruct it in your contract, but I suspect this would be very expensive to do. It would make a lost more sense to only pass the relevant data as independent variables.