# Is it possible to construct objects in javascript and pass it to Solidity?

Tags: solidity, javascript, truffle-migration, testing

Let's say I have these 2 contracts defined in the same solidity file.

```
contract Coin {
   string public name;
   constructor(string _name) public { 
      name = _name;
   }
}
contract MetaCoin {
   Coin public coin;
   constructor(Coin _coin) public {
       coin = _coin;
   }
   
}
```

Now I want to write a javascript migration in order to deploy so I tried the following

```
const coin = artifacts.require("Coin");
const meta = artifacts.require("Metacoin");

module.exports = async function (deployer, network, accounts) {

   await deployer.deploy(Coin,"diamond");
   const coin = await Coin.deployed();
   await deployer.deploy(MetaCoin, coin);
}
```

However my last line `await deployer.deploy(MetaCoin, coin);` causes an error since `coin` is not the correct thing to pass into the constructor of `MetaCoin`.

The error is pasted below

```
Error: while migrating Masterchef: invalid address (argument="address", value="[object Object]", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=address/5.0.5) (argument="_Pcake", value="[object Object
]", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.0.7)
```

I read the following question but I don't think it applies to my case since I define the `Coin` type.
[Can a Solidity function accept an object from JS. For example, can addTenant(**Tenant tenantObj**) accept Tenant Object?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/43946/can-a-solidity-function-accept-an-object-from-js-for-example-can-addtenantt/43947)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can just pass in the address of Coin instead of the Coin abstraction.

I ended up using

```
   await deployer.deploy(MetaCoin, coin.address);
```

I'm not sure why that ended up working so if someone could explain, that would help a lot.